# Where to put mocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to spec this action.

```
def get
    @asset = current_user.assets.find(params[:id])

    send_file @asset.uploaded_file.path, type: @asset.uploaded_file_content_type

    rescue ActionController::MissingFile
        redirect_to assets_url, error: 'missing file'
end
```

To test the send file method we mock it out.

```
controller.should_receive(:send_file)
```

**However, I have no idea where to put this mock:**

Here's how my spec looks:

```
subject { response }

let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }  
let!(:user_2) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }  
let!(:asset) { FactoryGirl.create(:asset, user_id: user.id) }
let!(:file) { fixture_file_upload('files/eve.jpg', 'image/jpeg') }
let!(:folder) { FactoryGirl.create(:folder, user_id: user.id, parent_id: nil) }

before do
  sign_in user
end

describe '#get' do
    context 'when exists' do
      before do
        get :get, id: asset.id
      end
      # controller.should_receive(:send_file).with(*args) <-- I need to test that
      it { should have_http_status 302 }
    end

    context 'when doesn\'t exist' do
      before do
        get :get, id: 765      
      end

      it { should redirect_to_location '/assets'}
      it { should set_flash_type_to :error }
      it { should set_flash_message_to 'missing file' }
    end
end
```

How do I test line 6. I want to keep the one line syntax if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in the `before` block

```
before do
  controller.should_receive(:send_file)
  get :get, id: asset.id
end
```